# How to make polymorphic field of class in C++? How to use polymorphism correctly in this case?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have a class

```
class A 
{
    BasePtr * ptr;
    virtual BasePtr * getPtr() { return ptr; }
    virtual void pure() = 0;
}
```

And I want to derive two classes from it that create its own versions of ptr:

```
class B : public A 
{
    B() : A() { ptr = new RoundPtr(); }
};

class C : public A 
{
    C() : A() { ptr = new SquarePtr(); }
}
```

Then I create a list of pointers to basic class:

```
A * list[2];
list[0] = new B();
list[1] = new C();
```

And call this method:

```
list[i]->getPtr();
```

But I found that it returns an uninitialized pointer.

So, how to correctly use polymorphism here? How to properly create this field to use different types of it?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, but if the errors are fixed in the obvious way then the pointer would be initialised. Please post real code.

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  As is the code wont compile.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/GDErEE) once the syntax errors and such are fixed.

Comment: Added compiling code as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tested this code and it works perfectly o_0 But I got crashed in more complex program when try to call method of polymorphic object pointer. Maybe I have an additional errors in my project.

The answer is:

```
#include <iostream>

class Ptr {
    public:
        Ptr(int x, int y) : centerX(x), centerY(y) {}
        virtual ~Ptr() {}
        virtual void foo() = 0;

    protected:
        int centerX, centerY;
};

class RoundPtr: public Ptr {
    public:
        RoundPtr(int x, int y, int radius) : Ptr(x, y), circleRadius(radius) {}
        virtual void foo() { std::cout << "RoundPtr, x: " << centerX << ", y: " << centerY << ", radius: " << circleRadius << std::endl; }

    protected:
        int circleRadius;
};

class SquarePtr: public Ptr {
    public:
        SquarePtr(int x, int y, int w, int h) : Ptr(x, y),
            leftX(centerX - w/2), leftY(centerY - h/2),
            width(w), height(h)
            {}

        virtual void foo() { std::cout << "SquarePtr, x: " << centerX << ", y: " << centerY << ", leftX: " << leftX << ", leftY: " << leftY << ", width: " << width << ", height: " << height << std::endl; }

    protected:
        int leftX, leftY;
        int width, height;
};

class A {
    protected:
        Ptr * ptr;

    public:
        A() : ptr(nullptr) {}
        virtual ~A() {}

        virtual Ptr * getPtr() { return ptr; }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B() : A() { ptr = new RoundPtr(0, 0, 10); }
        virtual ~B() { delete ptr; }
};

class C : public A {
    public:
        C() : A() { ptr = new SquarePtr(5, 5, 10, 10); }
        virtual ~C() { delete ptr; };
};

int main()
{
  A * bObj = new B();
  A * cObj = new C();

  bObj->getPtr()->foo();
  cObj->getPtr()->foo();

  delete bObj;
  delete cObj;
}
```

Can anybody check this code? Do you see any problems with it? Is it good solution? Is it possible to use smart pointers from c++11 here?